# Automatically add years to HTML select using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select input which will display years from this year until 1920.

However, my javascript code only seems to show it in ascending order.

```js
  var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 99,
    select = document.getElementById('year');

for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = i;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select name="year" id="year"></select>
```

So it needs to show:
2019
2018
2017...

Not:
1920
1921
1922

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways, use prepend, or simply count down instead of up. This method counts down. Unlike prepend, the highest is auto selected with counting down.

```js
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 99,
    select = document.getElementById('year');

for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = i;
  select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select name="year" id="year"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ParentNode#prepend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) method to append at the beginning and this will make the order in descending.

```js
var max = new Date().getFullYear(),
    min = max - 99,
    select = document.getElementById('year');

for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = i;
  select.prepend(opt);
}
```

```html
<select name="year" id="year"></select>
```